# PHP - How can I count the number of elements in the second dimension of a two dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array and I can't figure out how to count the number of elements in the second dimension of the array.

For example:

```
$array1 = array(1,1,0,1,2,1,4);
$array2 = array(1,1,1,2,1,4);
$array3 = array(1,1,0,1,4);

$multi_array = array($array1,$array2,$array3);
```

How can I count the number of elements in `$multi_array[0][1]` for example?

The output of:
`count($ALPHABET[0][0]);`

is `1` where it should be `7`

Comment: With [`count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)?

Comment: Either: `count`, or `sizeof` ... it's the same.

Comment: count($multi_array[0]) -> 7, count(multi_array[1]) -> 6, count(multi_array[2]) -> 5

Comment: `$multi_array[0][1]` is the integer 1. What do you expect it to be?

Comment: these are the basics ... ?

Comment: In this instance `$multi_array[0][1]` would be a value, not an array, do you mean `$multi_array[0]` ?

Comment: I want the count of the first element(array) in `$array1` hence `$ALPHABET[0][0]`

Comment: @Adam Westbrook - thanks that was it

Answer (score 2):

Treat every element as array

```
count($multi_array[index]);
```

I hope this can help

Comment: You have obviously not read his answer. It would be `count($ALPHABET[0]);` in your example, not `[0][0]`

Answer (score 0):

This might work (not tested)

```
$count = 0;
  foreach ($array as $type) {
  $count+= count($type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$multiarray[0][1] = 1`, not an array. You can do `count($multiarray[$index])` or sum them all by:

```
$total = 0;
foreach( $multiarray as $childarray ) {
  $total += count($childarray);
}
```

Or the equivalent:

```
$total = 0;
foreach( $i=0; $i<count($multiarray); $i++ ) {
  $total += count($multiarray[$i]);
}
```